# How do I connect this SPI serial display to an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, display

I've recently purchased a screen on DX without really thinking about it, because I have no idea how to connect it to my Arduino.

It is [this](http://www.dx.com/p/xs057-1-8-serial-128-x-160-spi-tft-lcd-module-display-for-arduino-black-white-golden-255430#.VWg4E8-eDRZ) screen:

[image: XS075]

The description says that it uses the SPI serial protocol but I don't know how to connect that ribbon to my Arduino, is soldering cables to it the only way?

Comment: I believe that this may be the specification: http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/18%E2%80%99%E2%80%99-tft-lcd-tft0118sp-p-671.html

Comment: There are a ton of pins coming out of that LCD.
I could imagine that it needs some kind of driver chip (which might be controlled through SPI).
I've recently ordered one (which looks rather similar) but with a "breakout" or driver board (http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-1-8-spi-lcd-module-with-microsd-led-backlight-for-arduino-mega-atmel-atmega.html/).

Answer (score 1):

That kind of connector is most commonly directly soldered on to a PCB.  You can [buy adaptor boards](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?&_nkw=fpc+adapter+board) with the various different pitch pads on them for soldering it to.

[image]

Also there is no mention of what chip the screen uses (I am unfamiliar with "XS057" as a chip, so that is probably the model of the screen not the chip).  At that resolution it's probably an ILI9163, but without being sure all you can do is stab wildly in the dark and try different drivers.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need! Thanks.
And I did find the datasheet on [this](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/18%E2%80%99%E2%80%99-tft-lcd-tft0118sp-p-671.html) website, so once I get that PCB I can most likely find my way. Thanks again!

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R698z9QaypY

Comment: Ah, it's an ST7735. That would have been my second choice.  Same basic chip as is used on the adafruit 1.8 shield: http://www.adafruit.com/products/802

Comment: On the datasheet I found [this](http://i.imgur.com/3fnJC45.png) specification, so that means I need an adapter for 0.40mm correct?

Comment: No, that's the pad width.  The one you are interested in is the "P+1.0 * 23 = 10.40", but that makes little sense to me.  The 10.40 is key though.   My calculations say that if you have 20.90 full width, with 5.25 gutter each side, that leaves 10.40 for the connector width (correct). With 14 pads that's then 13 spaces between them (from the center of the first to the center of the last), which is 10.40 / 13 = 0.8mm pitch.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the pinout you should be able to solder the hookup wires directly to the pins if you know how to use solder paste and a heat gun and skill if you are a beginner you need to put it in a box and order something from other suppliers more friendly to newbes.